# gVIM !start How to get the return value?

Tags: windows, vim

`!start` seems the only way to avoid taskbar blinking on Windows?
I know we can use system() to retrieve the return value, but I want to avoid the blinking.

So Is there any method including certain workarounds to get the return value from `!start`?

psudocode
`let g:return_value = !start /b program.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Small trick

```
:enew
:r! start /b program.exe
:let g:return_value=join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")
```

Info there : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Append_output_of_an_external_command

Answer (score 1):

`:!start` starts external programs into the background. At best it could tell you that the program you expect to start cannot start. As usual, with external program execution, this is stored into `v:shell_error`. However it seems that the `/b` flag prevents it to be filled. That's odd.

Any way, you cannot obtain the exit code of your program this way. Indeed, this makes no sense in such a scenario.

If you really want to start the program in the background, you'll get more information with `job_start()` & co: you'll know whether it could be started, you'll obtain what it prints, and you'll eventually obtain its exit code.

Otherwise, I'm afraid you'll only have `system()` that waits for the external program to end.